# Firebase Cloud Firestore read operation Resource Exhausted error under free quota limit?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore DB with my Django web application and since last evening I am getting following error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\signapp\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.ResourceExhausted: 429 Quota exceeded.
```

But when I checked the Firestore usage console I found that usage is under the free quota limit (within 50K)-
[image: firestore usage console]

Also when I checked the usage console in GCP, I found the usage different from the above-
[image: GCP_usage]

So does anyone know what is the correct usage metric here?
Without switching to a paid plan since my usage is under free quota how I can solve this ResourceExhausted error?

Answer (score 1):

Both metrics are correct.
Firestore DB write operation limit is 20K and I had crossed that limit.
So I was facing the issue.
I was confused between the read and write limit.